# Different simulator device ID between Jenkins and terminal

Tags: jenkins, ios-simulator

I use this statement `xcrun simctl list` to get device ID list, but it returns different list between Jenkins and terminal, so I can't start simulator via Jenkins.
[image: Picture on Jenkins]

And this's picture from terminal
[image: List device ID from terminal]

Answer (score 0):

I assume Jenkins is either running as a different user or on a different machine. Those identifiers are UDIDs (Universal Device IDs) which are UUIDs (Universally Unique Identifiers). They are globally unique for every user on every system.

simctl and xcodebuild accept device names so feel free to use "iPhone X" instead. You can also create new simulators with a custom name if you need to avoid collisions or select a specific OS version where you can't share UDIDs.